# Auth0 get profile of other user client side

Tags: auth0, user-profile, user-management

To learn some new technologies, I am building a small chat application that allows users to send messages to each other. I have set up my app with `auth0` for client authentication and user management. My chat messages include the `sub` of a user as the unique `author_id`.

Now, for my use case, I would like everyone who has received a message to pull up a small user profile card for the message author. This means querying the user management system with the `author_id` to retrieve the user profile.

I have found [the get users by id endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-search/retrieve-users-with-get-users-by-id-endpoint) which seems to fit my needs. The problem here is that this API requires a management API token, which will not be available on the client side.

Should I set up a pass-through API which authorizes users based on their app JWT token, and then requests the user profile from the `auth0` API with the management token? Or should I be looking at a different approach (the fact that this API requires a management token seems to suggest so)?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [rate limit](https://auth0.com/docs/troubleshoot/customer-support/operational-policies/rate-limit-policy) of the management API it is considered [better practice](https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-as-user-database/24316/4) to use an external database to save and retreive user data.